# Transform complex data by jolt processor in apache nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, transformation, jolt

I have following expected input and expected output and i want to transform data by jolt processor

**Input JSON**

```json
{
  "subscriptionId": "63",
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "demo",
      "Data": {
        "transactionId": "598958",
        "type": "json",
        "xyz": "pqr",
        "name": "john"
      },
      "nameData": [
        {
          "name": "Ama",
          "nameCount": "215",
          "genderData": [
            {
              "gender": "Male",
              "genderCount": "140"
            },
            {
              "gender": "Female",
              "genderCount": "75"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Aedes",
          "nameCount": "161",
          "genderData": [
            {
              "gender": "Female",
              "genderCount": "134"
            },
            {
              "gender": "Male",
              "genderCount": "27"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Culex",
          "nameCount": "2610",
          "genderData": [
            {
              "gender": "Male",
              "genderCount": "1926"
            },
            {
              "gender": "Female",
              "genderCount": "684"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Kamp",
          "nameCount": "465",
          "genderData": [
            {
              "gender": "Male",
              "genderCount": "465"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expected Output JSON**

```json
{
    "transactionId": "598958",
    "type": "json",
    "xyz": "pqr",
    "name": "john",
    "alert_array": [{
        "abc": "123",
        "xyz": "pqrs",
        "properties": [{
                "key": "Ama",
                "value": "215",
                "object": [{
                        "key": "Male",
                        "value": "140"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Female",
                        "value": "75"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "key": "Aedes",
                "value": "161",
                "object": [{
                        "key": "Male",
                        "value": "134"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Female",
                        "value": "27"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "key": "Culex",
                "value": "2610",
                "object": [{
                        "key": "Male",
                        "value": "1926"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Female",
                        "value": "684"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "key": "Kamp",
                "value": "465",
                "object": [{
                    "key": "Male",
                    "value": "465"
                }]
            },
            {
                "key": "type",
                "value": "demo"
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

I have the above following input JSON with nameData being an array and having genderData another array within it.
Need to convert the input JSON to expected JSON output as shown above.
please suggest JOLT spec to transform the above JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with determining the nodes `alert_array`,`properties`,`object` as diving to the innermost attributes within the shift transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "Da*": "",
          "nameD*": {
            "#123": "alert_array[0].abc", // # wildcard is used to add fixed values 
            "#pqrs": "alert_array[0].xyz",
            "*": {
              "name": "alert_array[0].properties[&1].key",
              "nameC*": "alert_array[0].properties[&1].value",
              "*": "alert_array[0].properties[&1].object"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // rename the innermost attributes
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "*": {
                  "key": "@(1,gender)",
                  "value": "@(1,genderCount)"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // get rid of the former names of the innermost attributes
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "*": {
                  "gender": "",
                  "genderCount": ""
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

**Edit** : You can add two more **shift** transformation specs in order to put the lately desired object

```json
{
  "key" : "type",
  "value" : "demo"
}
```

such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "Da*": "",
          "nameD*": {
            "#123": "alert_array[0].abc", // # wildcard is used to add fixed values 
            "#pqrs": "alert_array[0].xyz",
            "*": {
              "name": "alert_array[0].properties[&1].key",
              "nameC*": "alert_array[0].properties[&1].value",
              "*": "alert_array[0].properties[&1].object"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // rename the innermost attributes
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "*": {
                  "key": "@(1,gender)",
                  "value": "@(1,genderCount)"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // get rid of the former names of the innermost attributes
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "*": {
                  "gender": "",
                  "genderCount": ""
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "alert_array": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2[&1].&",
          "pro*": {
            "#type": "&3[&2].&1.&2.key",
            "#demo": "&3[&2].&1.&2.value",
            "*": "&3[&2].&1.&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "alert_array": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2[&1].&",
          "pro*": {
            "*": {
              "@": "&4[&3].&2"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Barbaros for sharing the solution . It was very helpful. I have edited the question and added  2 fixed key in alert_array (In output JSON). Can we made any change to get the desired output json? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks Barbaros for the solution. It was very helpful. Sorry, I missed one point .              
I have edited the output JSON and wish to have the attribute "type": "demo" coming in data array in input to come into properties array as shown in output json.

Comment: Hi @Barbaros Please try to help to resolve this problem . Yesterday I have tried more but not getting success. As I am new for JOLT transformation and this is urgently required for nifi template to be completed. Also sorry that I missed the key while asking the question.